# how to extract with beatifulsoup, problems with div

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract from the url all the Nacimientos, years of yesterday today and tomorrow, I try to extract all the `<li>`, but when a `<div>` appears it only extracts up to the `<div>`, try `next_sibling` and it didn't work either.

```
# Página objetivo
url = "https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/9_de_julio"

##Cantidad de articulos en español actuales. ##

# Obtener un requests de la URL objetivo
wikipedia2 = requests.get(url)

# Si el Status Code es OK! 
if wikipedia2.status_code == 200:
  nacimientos2 = soup(wikipedia2.text, "lxml")

else:
  print("La página respondió con error", wikipedia.status_code)

filtro= nacimientos2.find("section", id="mf-section-2")

anios= filtro.find('ul').find_all('li')

lista2 = []

for data in anios:
      lista2.append(data.text[:4])

lista2
```

Answer (score 0):

Main issue is that the focus of your selection is the first `<ul>` and all its `<li>`, you can simply adjust the selection while skipping the `<ul>`, cause your working on a specific `<section>`.

As one line with `list comprehension and` css selectors`:

```
yearList = [e.text[:4] for e in soup.select('section#mf-section-2 li')]
```

or based on your code -> `anios= filtro.find_all('li')`:

```
filtro= nacimientos2.find("section", id="mf-section-2")
anios= filtro.find_all('li')

lista2 = []

for data in anios:
      lista2.append(data.text[:4])
lista2
```